# Too many links...! One solution possible...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I have  61 links in my webpage. And for these 61 links, I would have to make 61 other pages...! That would be too much work. Is there a way to write the code of all the 61 links in one file, making sure only a particular link opens, which  has been selected?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following... Could you re-explain?

Comment: What you need is called a single-page-app. 

You can research about it and let us know if you face any doubts.

Comment: Are those pages similar in design? Like the only thing that changes are the data/content

Comment: use asp:RequiredFieldValidator  and validation group for only specific button.

Comment: you need a dynamic code, to draw/code all the page elements on one page.

Comment: That is a bad idea, as each user will need to download text for 61 pages but they still maybe only read 1, and as you still need to write the text, how can it be easier with 1 file? ... If you better explain how these 61 pages differs when it comes to headers, menus, footers etc. we might be able to help (and keep your question open since it at the moment is too broad and might close as such)